# Python md5 hash keeps generating wrong hash

Tags: python, hashlib

I'm using an online md5 generator to get the hash value of 'football'. When Python converts my input "football" at the prompt it generates a different hash. It then generates another totally different hash from the word "football" thats in my list. So no match when it compares them. I have hashed the word "football" in different online md5 generators and get the same result. Only in Python do i keep getting different results. Thanks for any help.

```
import hashlib


def dictionary_attack(password_hash):

    dictionary = ['letmein', 'password', '12345', 'football']

    password_found = None

    for dictionary_value in dictionary:
        temp_value = hashlib.md5('dictionary_value'.encode('utf-8'))
        hashed_value = temp_value.hexdigest()

        if hashed_value == password_hash:
            password_found = True
            recovered_password = dictionary_value

    if password_found == True:
        print(f'Found match for hashed value: {password_hash}')
        print(f'Password recovered: {recovered_password}')
    else:
        print(f'password not found')


def main():
    objhash = input('Enter value: ')
    hashobj = hashlib.md5('objhash'.encode('utf-8'))
    password_hash = hashobj.hexdigest()
    dictionary_attack(password_hash)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You're generating hash for the string `'dictionary_value'`, not `'football'`.

Comment: You're hashing the str `'objhash'` not the user input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not computing the hash of `"football"`. You're computing the hash of the string `"dictionary_value"`.

Change the line

```
temp_value = hashlib.md5('dictionary_value'.encode('utf-8'))
```

in `dictionary_attack` to

```
temp_value = hashlib.md5(dictionary_value.encode('utf-8'))
```

Likewise, in `main`, change

```
hashobj = hashlib.md5('objhash'.encode('utf-8'))
```

to

```
hashobj = hashlib.md5(objhash.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Really appreciate the help there bro. Nice one.